# arara and French

Tags: arara

The system is working but came with an example for german rather than French.

```
Running LuaLaTeX... SUCCESS
Running TeXindy... FAILURE
```

Presumably because I blindly edited

```
- identifier: german
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.german,"-g")}
```

into

```
- identifier: french                                                                                             
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.french,"-fr")}
```

taking the -fr flag from the manual.

What's the correct version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be modifying the `.yaml` files. The `.yaml` file defines the available options that are listed in the `{...}` part and indicates what switches they should implement when invoking the particular application.

```
- identifier: german
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.german,"-g")}
```

That looks like it's from the `makeindex.yaml` file. The `german` identifier is provided to add the `-g` switch to `makeindex`'s argument list. If you want it on, you add the following in your document:

```
% arara: makeindex: {german: on}
```

This means that `arara` will run the command `makeindex -g` *basename*`.idx`.

If you don't want it on then just do

```
% arara: makeindex
```

which will just run the command `makeindex` *basename*`.idx`. Makeindex doesn't have any other language switches.

It looks as though you actually want `texindy` rather than `makeindex`. In this case, `texindy` needs use the `-L` switch followed by the language name (which must be one that's supported by `xindy`). The actual command invocation is `texindy -L french` *basename*`.idx`. The `texindy.yaml` rule provides the `language` identifier to implement the `-L` switch.

For example:

```
% arara: texindy: {language: french}
```

and you may also need to added the encoding:

```
% arara: texindy: {language: french, codepage: utf8}
```

which changes the command invocation to `texindy -L french -C utf8` *basename*`.idx`.

The `texindy.yaml` rule provides the most commonly used options as identifiers. Any additional options can be added with the general purpose `options`. So an equivalent of the above is:

```
% arara: texindy: {options: [-L, french, -C, utf8]}
```